# Django admin inline classes without relation

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I have three model classes: Employee, Candidate and Report. Employee is registered as onetoone relation on Candidate model class. And Candidate is registered as foreign key on Report model class.

I want to display Employee reports (through Candidate) in Employee change form admin page. Tried to add as TabularInline but there is not direct relationship between Employee and Report and Django throws an exception. There is not such thing (probably, if I didn't miss) which will allow to specify "through" property.

Also looked up and there is an option of a third party package for nested inlines but due to limitations of current implementation, I am not able to use this package.

Can someone suggest how to handle this scenario so I don't need to write everything (html, css, js) on my own from scratch. Maybe there is some workaround which I am missing.

Thanks in advance.
P.S. I am using Django 2.2

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Employee, Candidate, Report

class ReportInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Report

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        candidate_ids = Candidate.objects.filter(employee=self.parent_obj).values_list('id', flat=True)
        return qs.filter(candidate__in=candidate_ids)
```

Register the inline form: Register the custom inline form with the Employee admin model.

```
class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      inlines = [ReportInline]

admin.site.register(Employee, EmployeeAdmin)
```

Try this solution!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cannot have ReportInline in EmployeeAdmin as they are not relation. Django will raise an error 'Report' has no ForeignKey to 'Employee'